# How to change gwt out files path in the war in the gradle script

Tags: gradle, gwt, path, war

I'm using gwt to generate few js files in my app.
I'm using Gradle for building my war file.
Here are important snippets from my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'gwt'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
        srcDirs=['src']
    }
  }
}

gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.8.0'
    modules 'com.wf.idc.facade.IdcFacade'
    modulePathPrefix = "/"

    maxHeapSize = "1024M"

    }

war {
  println 'building war'
  archiveName('IdcAdmin.war')
  destinationDir(file('dist'))

  from("src") {
    include '*.properties'
    into ('WEB-INF/classes')
  }

  from("web") {
    include 'login'
    include 'images'
    into ('/')
      }

  from("web") {
    include '*/*.*'
    include '**.*'    
    into ('/')
  }

  from("metadata/WEB-INF") {
    include '*.xml'
    into ('WEB-INF')
  }

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
        url 'http://artifactory.wf.com/artifactory/idc_maven_deploy_virtual'
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
    classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
    }
}
```

When the war gets created, the gwt files get created in the folder "com.wf.idc.facade.IdcFacade" at the root.

com.wf.idc.facade.IdcFacade/gwt

com.wf.idc.facade.IdcFacade/*.js files

I want the gwt folder and the all the js files generated at the root along with WEB-INF, META-INF level.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is as my build.gradle files are set and they do what you are looking for:

```
war {
        archiveName 'app.war'
}

gwt {
        gwtVersion= '2.8.0'

        modules 'com.test.app.App';
        devModules 'com.test.app.AppDev';
        maxHeapSize = "1G";

        superDev {
                noPrecompile = false;
                failOnError = false;
                bindAddress = "0.0.0.0";
        }

        compiler {
                strict = true
                enableClosureCompiler = false;
                disableClassMetadata = false;
                disableCastChecking = true;
        }
}
```

I hope that helps.